# error in using make for creating a simple hello world kernel module

Tags: drivers

I have just started learning kernel module programming. I started by writing a simple hello world
module. The code of the module is as follows.

```c
# include <linux/module.h>
# include <linux/kernel.h>
int entry_function(void){
   printk("Hello world from init module /n");
   return 0;
}
void exit_function(void){
  printk("Good Bye from exit module /n");
   
}
module_init(entry_function);
module_exit(exit_function);
MODULE_AUTHOR("name");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DISCRIPTION("A simple module developed as demo");
```

I tried to compile this module by making a make file. The code for make file is below

```
obj-m:=helloworld_module.o
```

I compiled the module with following command

```sh
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r` /M=/home/bharat/helloworld/
```

On this, I got the following error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:264: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-112-generic'***
```

Please help me to rectify this error.